# No errors for too many delimiters in t-sql bulk insert

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, error-handling, bulkinsert

I'm trying to use T-SQL Bulk Insert command to insert data from a pipe delimited text file into a table.

```
BULK INSERT #compprofiletable 
FROM ''' + @FileLocation + '''
WITH (DATAFILETYPE = ''char'',
      CODEPAGE = ''RAW'',
      FIELDTERMINATOR = ''|'', 
      FIRSTROW = 2,
      ROWTERMINATOR = ''0x0a'')
```

I'm expecting 3 columns of data in my text file.

```
Date|Company_Profile|Profile_Stat
12/31/2014|First Closing|7/31/2014
```

However I'm getting data with too many delimiters in the text:

```
Date|Company_Profile|Profile_Stat
12/31/2014|First Clo|sing|7/31/2014
```

Normally I would expect this to cause the Bulk Insert command to fail, however the extra "pipes" are just ignored and inserted into the last column of the table.

[image]

Is there a way of capturing this error so that I can roll back the insert?

I'm not getting any errors from the Bulk insert command above and I have 1000's of rows so I wouldn't want to post-process the columns of data.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: One option might be to turn `CHECK_CONSTRAINTS` on in your bulk insert and add a check constraint to the last column of your table that disallows pipe characters.  It's a bit of a hack, but I think it would work.

Comment: I'll give that a go and let you know the results... it's not as clean as I would like but if it works...